# 'sudo' commands are slow while on network

Tags: rhel, sudo

**Problem:**

- Running sudo commands take up to 30 seconds to execute. Time it takes is not consistent, sometimes the command returns quickly if it was previously called, but most of the time it takes much longer than it should. Additionally, when sudo is run while **off** the network, it responds instantly, but as soon as I connect the machine to my WIFI, it becomes slow.

**Environment**

- *OS*: Redhat7 Enterprise Linux
- *Hardware:* HP Zbook G3
- Smart card authentication is enabled
- `sudo -V`:

> ```
>   Sudo version 1.8.6p7
>   Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.6p7
>   Sudoers file grammar version 42
>   Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.6p7
> ```

**Solutions tried but failed:**

- Hostname is on both lines in /etc/hosts
- Running `sudo strace -f -t sudo echo` proved that the first sudo is the one that hangs, the second sudo command executes normally as expected.
- I changed the permissions of strace so I could run it as my username, so I ran `strace -f -t sudo echo` and lo and behold the command returns instantly, and does not hang. This is unfortunate because I can't seem to run strace on the sudo command to see where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Hi. You say this happens with *any* sudo command, but the subject line includes "yum".  This is confusing.  Could you please clarify with a specific command you tried, which is simpler than `sudo yum`  (and is also delayed).  E.g. `time sudo echo Hello world`.  If so, it would be great to remove "yum" from the subject line & tags.

Comment: Sorry, it is not any Sudo command, only sudo yum commands

Comment: Judging from the output you provided of the two commands, they're not even doing the same thing. I would first focus on why they're not doing the same thing before I worry about why one is slower than the other.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the right output. The point remains though that all sudo yum commands are extremely slow compared to not using sudo.

Comment: Your output is still different between the two commands. If you're saying you provided the wrong output, we will be unable to help you unless we get accurate information.

Comment: This question is very unclear and internally inconsistent. I'd recommend a complete re-edit, taking on board the above comments. I'd also suggest clarifying what you mean by "connect to my own network". I presume you are referring to system changes made by Network Manager (but you haven't given enough information to know for sure). If so, you should check what those changes are, e.g., changing the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` could cause problems with authentication.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` delays have often been caused by DNS issues.

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=210503

One user had a similar 2 minutes delay caused by the issue: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=93387b186c8850e6837cea5f7a43457c&p=1194582&postcount=2

Therefore this is my first line of investigation.  You could try checking `time getent hosts $(hostname)`, and seeing if there's a delay there.

Note: my understanding is the reason this kept happening had been fixed upstream.  It would be very interesting if you could note the version of `sudo` used by your distribution.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=479464#c9

Otherwise, confirm the problem happens with the inner sudo of `sudo time sudo echo`. Then you could try running `sudo strace -t -f sudo echo`. There will be a lot of output, but it will be timestamped. You will see some system call where the delay is spent, e.g. recvmsg (receive message, possibly waiting with a timeout, possibly a DNS response). Full interpretation requires programming knowledge.  If something goes via dbus then I guess it won't show which dbus service specifically.  (Feel free to post the full output somewhere and link to it - dropbox.com, gist.github.com, etc).

Comment: I've updated my question with some results from your suggestions. Still not having any luck though.