# Sudo command hangs

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

Every time I try to execute `sudo su -` or any other `sudo` command for this matter my server hangs, sometimes it take 10 mins to respond and sometimes it never does.

I checked `/etc/hosts` file which was configured correctly. I also checked `/etc/resolv.conf` file which looked good as well.
any suggestions?

I am running redhat 6.9

Comment: So,  do you have any way of becoming root?

Comment: Yes.. Sometimes it allows me to become root

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo` after you’re already root?  Does it still hang then?  If so, you might try running ``strace`` (or some similar program) on it.

Comment: When does it hang -- before asking for the password or after? (Also, `strace sudo -i` or so might be your friend, even if its output is daunting, because you can see what it's trying to do when it hangs.)

Comment: I have not tried to run sudo while I am already root but I will try that.. I will also run strace sudo and post the output tomorrow

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365599/sudo-commands-are-slow-while-on-network

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `strace` is usually a good idea and I almost suggested this myself, but since `sudo` has the `setuid` bit set, `strace` will (should) not be able to attach :-|  @Ahmed: if you eventually manage to get root, does it also hang when you do `sudo -u $someuser -i`? If so, then try that with `strace`.

Comment: Do you have PAM installed. If so, check the config files if you're using some kind of remote authentification (e.g., LDAP)

Comment: On your `/etc/hosts` you shoud have `127.0.0.1  hostname` ; `hostname` =`echo $HOSTNAME`

Comment: @GAD3R I think that resolved my issue

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 on a newly created openstack remote vm. `sudo su` hanged for many seconds, maybe up to a minute, before it either worked or not. When it worked it could be made quick and reliable by running this once as root:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 localhost $(hostname) >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem can reproduced when the hostname is changed , edit your `/etc/hosts` by adding the output of `echo $HOSTNAME` after `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1  hostname
```

Comment: I configured it correctly, the issue was fixed but now its back again for no reason. Not sure what the issue is still :(

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by multiple `sudo` processes running/hanging in the background, processes like `sudo chmod g+rwx -R folders_with_many_files`.

What helped was

```
ps -aleF | grep sudo
```

first to inspect, later something like

```
ps -aleF | grep sudo | awk '{print $4}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Same problem. It solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by a missing package. Unfortunately you'll need to use sudo to install it ;) I would recommend `sudo su` then `apt install libnss-myhostname`

Comment: This worked for me, with the caveat that I had to modify /etc/nsswitch.conf and place "myhostname" as the first entry in the hosts list. When I installed it was appended to the end of the list by default, so that the "myhostname" method would only be used if all other dns methods failed to resolve the address.

Answer (score 0):

I came here after discovering that `sudo docker ps` would hang forever on my fresh `raspberry pi 4` with a ubuntu 20.04.

Putting the value of `$HOSTNAME` behind `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` seemed to have made sudo "more accessible".

But still docker would not run properly. `apt upgrade` failed for docker also, I couldn't even kill the process with `ctrl + c`, but had to `pkill apt` and then kill the process of `dpkg` by its `PID`.

Doing `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as suggested by another ´apt upgrade´, hung at docker-ce package again.

BUT during the first ´apt upgrade´ a new kernel had been installed. So I tried my luck with rebooting. Now it works again. Someone else had a similar experience here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236208/docker-ps-stuck-docker-install-also-just-hangs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after removing below config in `/etc/sudoers`, everything runs ok:

```
Defaults       use_pty
```